# Invalid character error running Oracle statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
Private Function GetSumm(ByVal strLot As String) As DataSet

Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = smsdw; User ID = rpt; Password = rpt;"

Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)

Dim queryString As String = "select smsdw.device_def from smsdwSI6;"

Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
Return dataSet

End Function
```

Gives:

```
Error at dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SQL statement does not include a trailing semi-colon. That is a statement separator in SQL*Plus and other clients, not part of the statement itself. (PL/SQL is a different story).

Anyway, just remove the semi-colon:

```
Dim queryString As String = "select smsdw.device_def from smsdwSI6"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error due to copying from editor(in my case Excel).
[this article](http://www.wikitechy.com/fix-error/ORA-00911-invalid-character-n) solved my problem.

solution- Don't copy paste from any editors in visual studio.